# Could we write $(a+b)^* = (\epsilon + a + b)^+$?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have read that $L^* = L^+ - \epsilon$, but if we write $(\epsilon + a + b)^+$,  is it equivalent to $(a+b)^*$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i think it need to be equal but i have given a test where its showing its not equal.. so got confuse also one more question is epsilon+ = epsilon ??

Comment: If you're not sure, try to prove that $(a+b)^* = (\epsilon+a+b)^+$. This is how we know whether mathematical statements are true or not.

Comment: Regarding your other question, the rule is one question per post.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus could you please give me some hint, how should i proceed, logically if i think kleen plus doesnot contain epsilon, but if we are writing epsilon as symbol inside it can produce epsilon, dont you think both things are contradicting.. thats why i am confuse.. how should i prove it.. ??

Comment: To prove that $A=B$, you have to show that $x \in A$ implies $x \in B$ and vice versa. In your case you can also use identities of regular expressions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus help me out with this thing.. if i write (epsilon)+ what will be result because according to me (anything)^+ = (anything) - epsilon, so (epsilon)^+ = epsilon - epsilon, which is equivalent to phi, so even though we are including epsilon in (epsilon + a + b)^+, it has no meaning it will become null or phi, so using this logic i can say both are not equivalent.. am i correct

Comment: If you want to ask another question, you'll have to ask it as a separate question. That's how this site works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49660/discussion-between-shaji-thorn-blue-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: "I have read that $L^*=L^+−\epsilon$". That's certainly not true, since $\epsilon\in L^*$ always. Perhaps you meant to write that $L^+ = L^*-\epsilon$, but even that's not true when $\epsilon\in L$. So did you mean to write _plus_, instead of minus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have read that $L^∗=L^+−\epsilon$

That's definitely not true, since $\epsilon\in L^*$ but $\epsilon\notin [\text{anything}]-\epsilon$. If you still know where you read this, I suggest you check to see if you've misremembered what was written.

> but if we write $(\epsilon+a+b)^+$, is it equivalent to $(a+b)^∗$?

Yes. The first regular expression matches any string that can be broken up into one or more units, where each unit is either empty, an $a$ or a $b$. That matches the empty string (every unit is empty) or any string of positive length containing only $a$s and $b$s (every unit is $a$ or $b$). The second regular expression matches any string that can be broken up into zero or more units, each of which is an $a$ or a $b$. That matches the empty string (no units at all) or any string of positive length containing only $a$s and $b$s (one or more units).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a bit of a semantic confusion. It's not true that $\epsilon \notin e^+$, because the definition of $e^+$ is not $e^* - \{\epsilon\}$; rather $e^+$ is $e \cdot e^*$. It's a bit nuanced, but these two definitions disagree whenever $e$ is nullable, because $ee^*$ is still nullable while $e^* - \{\epsilon\}$ is no longer nullable by definition.

Here's one way to test this hypothesis, assuming that $e^+ = ee^*$. Recall that regular expression forms roughly what we would call a semiring in that operations are associative ($\small(a + b) + c = a + (b + c) = a + b + c$, $\small(ab)c = a(bc) = abc$) and $\cdot$ distributes into $+$ ($\small l(a + b) = la + lb, (a + b)r = ar + br$). Unfortunately, it is not commutative, since ordering in words matter, but it is a $+$-idempotent (semi)ring in that $a + a = a$.

Given this ring-like characterization, we're allowed to borrow any numerical tools that doesn't rely on commutativity in our analysis.

**Hypothesis**: $(a+b)^* = (\epsilon + a + b)^+$ for all regular expressions $a, b$

*Proof*: Let's start by expanding the left side.
$$
(a + b)^* = \epsilon + (a + b) + (a+b)^2 + \cdots
$$
Similarly, we can expand the right side as
\begin{align*}
(\epsilon + a + b)^+ &= (\epsilon + (a + b))^+ & \text{associativity} \\
&= (\epsilon + (a + b)) + (\epsilon + (a + b))^2 + \cdots \\
&\text{   by the binomial theorem} \\
&= \sum_n \left(\sum_k^n {n \choose k} \epsilon^{n - k} (a + b)^k\right) \\
&= \sum_n \left(\sum_k^n {n \choose k} (a + b)^k\right) & \text{since }\epsilon e = e \\
&= \sum_n \left(\sum_k^n (a + b)^k\right) & \text{since }na = a, \text{ if } n > 0 \\
&= \sum_k (a + b)^k & \text{again by idempotence} \\
&= \underbrace{(a + b)^0}_{\epsilon} + (a + b)^1 + (a + b)^2 + \dots
\end{align*}
Since the two sides agree, they are necessarily equivalent, though the right side is necessarily "ambiguous." $\square$

There's a few ingredients of this proof. The main one is how we absorb redundant subexpressions via idempotence, but the ability to use the binomial theorem is pretty cool too.

Comment: A technicality. There is no binomial theorem for regular expressions in general: $(a+b)^2 = aa +ab + ba + bb$ which does not equal $a^2+2ab+b^2$. The reason is that concatenation is not associative. Here you use it for $\epsilon$ which does work, but I do not know what ${n\choose k} (a+b)^k$ means? How to multiply an expression by a number?

Comment: The theorem isn't general, but in this specific case it gives a compact description which is useful. In general, $(\epsilon + e)^k$ is amenable to this biomial expansion since identities commute with respect to $\cdot$. Of course, commutativity breaks down in the general case so this doesn't hold of, say, $(a + b)^k$.

$ne$ where $n$ is a positive integer can be interpreted as $e + \cdots + e$, which by idempotency of $+$ reduces down to just $e$.

Comment: -1 for proving an elementary fact with something so baroque that I can't even tell if it's a proof or not. I'm sorry, but that's not cool at all.

Answer (score 0):

A more general theorem, which holds for any regular expression $r$, is

> $r^* = (r+\epsilon)^+$.

The proof is straightforward, using the definitions of $s^+,s^*$. The exact proof depends on your exact definition. A related theorem is

> $r^* = (r+\epsilon)^*$.

I encourage you to prove these results using the definitions you learned in class.